# File content copy to another file using C++

Tags: c++, file, inputstream, outputstream, turbo-c++

I am pretty new to C++ programming. My objective is to copy the content of one file into another file.

My code like below:

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<fstream.h>

int main(){
    ifstream file1;
    ofstream file2;
    char ch;
    char sfile[10], tfile[10];
    cout<<"\nEnter the source filename: ";
    cin>>sfile;
    cout<<"\nEnter the target filename: ";
    cin>>tfile;

    file2.open(sfile);
    file2<<"hello world";
    file2.close();

    file1.open(sfile);
    file2.open(tfile);

    while(!file1.eof()){
        file1.get(ch);
        cout<<ch;
        if(file1.get(ch) == " "){
            continue;
        }
    file2<<ch;
    }
    file1.close();
    file2.close();
    return 0;
}
```

However I am not getting the correct result in the output file. It should have been `helloworld` but I am getting `el olÿ` in the output file.

Not sure what wrong am I doing here. Can anyone please help me in this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: Also, don't call file1.get() multiple times per iteration, or you are moving the file pointer forward too much.

Comment: What do you think happens when you do `file1.get(ch)` *twice* in a single loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems here:

1. [Don't use `std::ifstream::eof()` as loop condition.](/q/5431941/5958455)
2. Don't compare a character against a string literal. Use single quotes for character literals.
3. Don't call `get()` twice, you'll lose half of the characters.

Change the loop to:

```
while (file1.get(ch)) {
    cout << ch;
    if (ch == ' ') {
        continue;
    }
    file2 << ch;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are code is correct , the tfile has "helloworld" in it. but it wont be displayed as such when you open it directly. you can check contents of tfile by using the code above to display the data.